# disconnected from airflow docker container after ~10 s

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile, airflow

I successfully created and started this container :

> https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow

by running :

```
docker build --rm --build-arg AIRFLOW_DEPS="datadog,dask" --build-arg PYTHON_DEPS="flask_oauthlib>=0.9" -t puckel/docker-airflow .

docker-compose -f docker-compose-CeleryExecutor.yml up -d
```

Then i just wanted to add java to images :

I added at the end :

> https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow/blob/master/Dockerfile#L83

```
USER airflow
WORKDIR ${AIRFLOW_USER_HOME}
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["webserver"] # set default arg for entrypoint

# my new code :
USER root
RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man1/

# Install OpenJDK-8
RUN apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk && \
apt-get install -y ant && \
apt-get clean;

# Fix certificate issues
RUN apt-get update && \
apt-get install ca-certificates-java && \
apt-get clean && \
update-ca-certificates -f;
# Setup JAVA_HOME -- useful for docker commandline
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
```

After building and running the container, 
i'm trying to connect like i did before instaling java :

> docker exec -it docker-airflow_worker_1  /bin/bash

But i'm automaticaly disconnected. And java is installed

```
root@5475d28fb5f5:/usr/local/airflow# java -version 
openjdk version "1.8.0_232"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_232-8u232-b09-1~deb9u1-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.232-b09, mixed mode)
root@5475d28fb5f5:/usr/local/airflow# %
```

And when i log the container :

```
User information: uid=0 euid=0 gid=0 egid=0

[2019-10-31 12:07:40,312] {{settings.py:213}} INFO - settings.configure_orm(): Using pool settings. pool_size=5, max_overflow=10, pool_recycle=1800, pid=1
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.
  """)
[2019-10-31 12:07:40,621] {{__init__.py:51}} INFO - Using executor CeleryExecutor
Running a worker with superuser privileges when the
worker accepts messages serialized with pickle is a very bad idea!

If you really want to continue then you have to set the C_FORCE_ROOT
environment variable (but please think about this before you do).

User information: uid=0 euid=0 gid=0 egid=0
```

Can anyone help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you changed user to root in Dockerfile and Airflow now refuses to start. Try to move your new code in Dockerfile before `USER airflow` line. Also you can delete `USER root` line after that.